# MSI Laptop rt3090 Wireless LAN hard blocked, how do I unblock it?

Tags: 11.10, wireless, laptop, ralink, msi

In rfkill list my wireless lan shows as "hard blocked". How can I unblock it?

Comment: I don't own one, so I can't tell you where the switch or what the key combination is.  You don't list the laptop model only the wireless module, so I can't google for a diagram.  Hard-block indicates a switch, bios disable, or key combination to disable the hardware.

Comment: @aking1012 Thanks for looking. I tried all the options available in various forums, but it turned out to be a very peculiar issue. There indeed is a Fn + F8 key combo for this but it wouldn't work. I opened the terminal for checking something else and pressed the Fn + F8 keys and surprise! The Wireless LAN turned on! So, the issue here is The Fn key combination works when we are in the terminal mode and does not work in other (GUI) windows. I use CCSM - so would it be trapping the Fn key press?

Comment: The laptop is CR400.

Comment: It's possible that it's getting trapped by any number of things.  At least you have a semi-workable solution.  File a bug report against the driver.  They'll say it's not their problem and suggest a package to file a bug report against.  Keep following the blame game until you get results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP Posted:

> I tried all the options available in various forums, but it turned out to be a very peculiar issue. There indeed is a Fn + F8 key combo for this but it wouldn't work. I opened the terminal for checking something else and pressed the Fn + F8 keys and surprise! The Wireless LAN turned on! So, the issue here is The Fn key combination works when we are in the terminal mode and does not work in other (GUI) windows.

Comment: Fn + F8 key combo also works to activate the WiFi in 12.04 Xubuntu installed on a HP Compaq tc4200, forget the dedicated wifi unblock button on the side of the laptop