# Why is my Intel 2200BG wifi card hard-blocked?

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I have installed 12.04 on a Fujitsu Siemens Amilo Pro.  Wifi card does not work.  Have tried various threads but none have the same problem.  Think I have the correct firmware but the following comes up:

```
gill@ubuntu:~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth1      IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Channel:0  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Bit Rate:0 kb/s   Tx-Power=off   Sensitivity=8/0  
          Retry limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

Also:

```
gill@ubuntu:~$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

There is a power switch for wifi but it does not do anything in Ubuntu.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Have you found any solutions since then?

Comment: I have the same problem, but would like to provide more info to hopefully solve it. Should I open a separate question (although it could be regarded a duplicate)?

Comment: Please look at this post http://askubuntu.com/q/107169/37991 for something to try.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try
`rfkill unblock all` ?

Comment: afaik this can only remove soft-blocks, but his chip is hard-blocked.

Comment: On my Dell this unblocks the hard-block too. The Wifi indicator turns on like when I press Fn + F8.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: @Mitch This is in question form, but it's an answer--it's intended as a solution to the problem (and might work).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [FSAM module](http://zwobbl.homelinux.net/pub/) as per http://rfswitch.sourceforge.net/?page=laptop_matrix ?